# Get one of many values from freebase?

Tags: freebase, mql

Suppose I am trying to get the wikipage title of all freebase entities with type "/people/person"

```
[{
  "type": "/people/person",  
  "mid": null,  
  "key": [{  
    "namespace": "/wikipedia/en",  
    "value": null  
  }]  
}]
```

This returns me the following

```
"result": [  
    {  
      "type": "/people/person",  
      "key": [  
        {  
          "value": "Ann_Copland",  
          "namespace": "/wikipedia/en"  
        },  
        {  
          "value": "Jack_Abramof",  
          "namespace": "/wikipedia/en"  
        },  
        {  
          "value": "Jack_Abramoff",  
          "namespace": "/wikipedia/en"  
        },  
        ....
```

Here Ann_Copland, Jack_Abramof, Jack_Abramoff all redirect to the same wikipedia page.

I only want one of the titles (Ann_Copland, Jack_Abramof, Jack_Abramoff ...) from the freebase query. Of course, I can query as above, and ignore the extra titles, but is there a smarter way of specifying the number of results that I expect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure about this, but it seems like the following is returning unique pages:

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=[{"name":[],"type":"/people/person"}]
```

To get unique value from your query add "limit":

```
https://www.googleapis.com/freebase/v1/mqlread?query=[{
  "type": "/people/person",  
  "mid": null,  
  "key": [{  
    "limit": 1,
    "namespace": "/wikipedia/en",  
    "value": null  
  }]  
}]
```

Comment: yes, but this is not returning wikipage title. Perhaps I can simply use this, though this does not solve the original problem.

Comment: OK, maybe I didn't understand what you want. You just want to limit the items limited by your query?